# Operator<< Overloading not working right for complex numbers

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, istream

I have a programming assignment where I have to overload the operator<<(istream,class) method.

The idea is that you could type into the command console a complex number like 5.6 + 6.7i and
then you could use cin to get that data and store it into a ComlexNumber object.
cin<

here is the overloaded method

```
istream & operator>>(istream & in, ComplexNumber & n){
double real;
double imag;
in>>real;
char _operator;
in.get(_operator);
while(_operator == ' ' || _operator == '\n' || _operator == '\t'){
    in.get(_operator);
}
int mult;
switch(_operator){
    case '+':
        mult = 1;
        break;
    case '-':
        mult = -1;
        break;
    default :
        in.setstate(ios::failbit);
        return in;              
};
in>>imag;
imag *= mult;   
n = ComplexNumber(real,imag);
return in;
}
```

The issue is that when i try to test the code with the console when I type in a complex number only the real part of the number gets the right value the imaginary part always gets 0. I think it has something to do with the fact that I'm trying to parse a number that is right next to an 'i' character. The weird thing is that the code worked fine when i stored the values as integers but not for doubles. Does anyone know why this is and if there is a solution around it?

Comment: Which `operator` are you having issues with?  Your title says `<<` but the code says `>>`.

Comment: I suggest you search StackOverflow for "[c++] complex number input" and see what turns up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ operator overloading for complex number operations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348058/c-operator-overloading-for-complex-number-operations)

Answer (score 0):

I gotta admit I ran your code and it **works**. I think you have the problem with the constructor (`ComplexNumber(double,double)`), or with the overloaded `operator =`. This is my test code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class ComplexNumber{
   friend istream & operator>>(istream &in, ComplexNumber &in);
}; 

istream & operator>>(istream & in, ComplexNumber & n){
double real;
double imag;
in>>real;
char _operator;
in.get(_operator);
while(_operator == ' ' || _operator == '\n' || _operator == '\t'){
    in.get(_operator);
}
int mult;
switch(_operator){
 case '+':
     mult = 1;
     break;
 case '-':
     mult = -1;
     break;
 default :
     in.setstate(ios::failbit);
     return in;              
};
in>>imag;
imag *= mult;   
cout << real << " " << imag << endl;
return in;
} 

int main(){
   ComplexNumber c;
   cin >> c;

   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

I've tried inputting:

- 3.0+2.0i
- 1-2
- 1231.1231+234.41i
- 214   +3.14

Comment: I tried my code on the school computers and it does work fine just not on my Computer. What version of g++ were you using?

Comment: I was using DevC++ 4.9.9.2, it uses gcc version 3.4.2 (mingw-special) as the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Although your code can be simplified (and possibly corrected to be a proper input operator), it should actually work as it. It certainly does work for me. Does your constructor of `ComplexNumber` set both the `real` and `imag` part?

Here are a few suggestions:

1. Skipping whitespace can be done a lot simpler using the `std::ws` manipulator:

   ```
   in >> std::ws;
   ```

   Of course, if you just use a formatted read for the `_operator` you can just read the entire value in one go:

   ```
   char _operator, i;
   if (in >> real >> _operator >> imag >> i) { ... }
   ```
2. Your code currently leaves the trailing `i` in the stream. It should, instead, probably read the value and verify that there is, indeed an `'i'` character.
3. You should always check *after* reading that a value was successfully read!
4. A proper input operator starts off with creating a `sentry` object: this object flushes a potentially `tie()`d output stream (e.g., `std::cout` is `tie()`d to `std::cin`), skips leading whitespace, and checks if the stream is good:

   ```
   std::istream::sentry cerberos(in);
   if (cerberos) {
       // the main operation goes here
   }
   ```